# How to use v-show inside a loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Thanks @zero298, the dup doesn't apply in important ways.  I want to show all of the items in the object array, just conditionally add some UI to each based on user signal.  Furthermore, v-if and v-show are very different (as noted here and elsewhere).  vue q/a on this site seems to be pretty light -- because it's new -- seems like a mistake to aggressively close on such a new topic.

I can make show work this way...

(NOTE... Please run the snippets in "Expand Snippet" mode to see the behavior over the console stuff.  Not sure how to suppress the vue messages in console)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
  }
});
```

```css
.demo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h3>Hi there</h3>
    <div class="demo" @click="show = !show">Click me</div>
    <div v-show="show">Show or hide me</div>
</div>
```

But why can't I make it work this way...

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    objects: [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ],
    show: [false, false, false]
  },
  methods: {
  }
});
```

```css
.demo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(object, i) in objects">
      <h3>Hi there {{ object.name }} show status is {{ show[i] }}</h3>
      <div class="demo" @click="show[i] = !show[i]">Click me</div>
      <div v-show="show[i]">Show or hide me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've seen doc content saying not to use v-if in a loop, but what's wrong with v-show?  There's evidence that the @click expression assigning to the show array isn't running (see the variable state next to the "hello" message), but why not?

I've tried moving that logic to a method, and moving the v-show check to a method, but with the same results.

Also, my array of objects will appear async and have an unknown (but small) length.  I don't want to add a "show" property to those objects because user can save them back to the server.  What's the right time and place to allocate a `show` array of bools that matches the objects array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to handle v-if with v-for in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518609/correct-way-to-handle-v-if-with-v-for-in-vue)

Comment: The dupe I linked is pertinent to your statement: *"I've seen doc content saying not to use v-if in a loop, but what's wrong with v-show?"*.  It's not that you shouldn't use `v-if/show` in a `v-for` it's that you shouldn't make the renderer do a bunch of logic that it shouldn't need to.  Pre-filter the items that shouldn't be visible.  Your case is the same.

Comment: Thanks @zero298, but *all the items must be visible*.  Just some extra buttons might be shown for each, controlled by the user.  My case is not the same at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This because of vue's change detection. Vue cannot detect that the array is changing.
You have to do something like this to detect it:

```
<div class="demo" @click="$set(show, i, !show[i])">Click me</div>
```

Helpful: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: [Vue can see the Array is changing](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods), you're linking to v1 docs.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks very much!  INSANE that this should be marked as a dup (the dup in question very off-point).  Not sure who downvoted, but this is just what I need and will use. (upvoted and will accept as soon as i am allowed)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't know it either. You can also mark it as correct answer, so everyone can see this question is settled.

Comment: Yup.  Thanks.  I was time limited in marking it correct.  Really, a big mistake, IMO, to mark dups as if this is a 20 year old tag.

Comment: @someShmuck Age of a tag plays no importance on whether to close a question or not.  Don't take people marking your question as a duplicate as a slight.  Your question sounded very similar due to your misunderstanding of the relation between `v-if/show` and `v-for`.

Comment: @Phil - any advice on the other aspect of the question (or maybe its a dup, too).  When  to allocate the bool array if the object array is populated async in the store?  Thanks.

Comment: @zero298 - you know about policy stuff better than I, and no offense taken about the dup.  It is an incorrect dup, however. And, had it been marked this way before this helpful answer, it have left me stuck (and I've been stuck for awhile).