# VueJS computed property vs v-if, performance

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuejs2, time-complexity

I have a data array, and each item in the array has a `state` property that contains one of these values, `allowed`, `pending`, `rejected`. I want to display data in separate sections based on their `state`. Each data card has two buttons on it that can be used to change item `state`.

I'm using three computed properties to separate data like so:

```js
computed: {
    pendingData() {
        return this.data.filter(x => x.state === 'pending')
    },
    allowedData() {
        return this.data.filter(x => x.state === 'allowed')
    },
    rejectedData() {
        return this.data.filter(x => x.state === 'rejected')
    }
}
```

and I display them in their own section using `v-for`.

Changing `state` occurs through an API call, so I need to send the id of item and new state to `setState` function:

```html
<div class="state-change-buttons">
    <button @click="setState(item.id, 'allowed')">
        <span uk-icon="icon: check; ratio: 1.4"></span>
    </button>
    <button @click="setState(item.id, 'pending')">
        <span uk-icon="icon: future; ratio: 1.4"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

and this is `setState` function:

```js
setState(id, state) {
    const index = this.data.findIndex(x => x.id === id)
    this.$axios.post(`/api/${id}`, {state})
        .then(res => {
            this.data.splice(index, 1, res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.$notify(err, 'danger')
        })
}
```

As you can see, to update my data array in realtime I have to find the index of selected item using `findIndex`.

[Vue style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential) suggests not to use `v-if` on the same element as `v-for`. But should I still avoid it, even if it decreases my app, time complexity?

current scenario:
3 computed property (O(3n)) + findIndex (O(n)) + 3 v-for (O(p + r + q))

conditional `v-for`:
3 conditional v-for (O(3n)) (no findIndex, this way I can pass index to `setState` directly)

conditional `v-for` code:

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in data" v-if="item.state === 'pending'" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
</div>

<div v-for="(item, index) in data" v-if="item.state === 'allowed'" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
</div>

<div v-for="(item, index) in data" v-if="item.state === 'rejected'" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the `v-if` and `v-for` fit in your template, can you add that?  Because from what I'm seeing and understanding, they shouldn't be on the same root element either way.

Comment: @StevenB. I added the code at the end of my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to handle v-if with v-for in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518609/correct-way-to-handle-v-if-with-v-for-in-vue)

Comment: Using v-if with v-for is not recommended https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether `v-if` is related to the parent or the child. You can use a template to resolve this issue:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in data">
  <div v-if="item.state === 'rejected'" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It's the opposite, v-for has higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment to your question says I can't understand either your computation without seeing the 2 proposed templates. 
Nevertheless, this is my personal preference when facing this kind of lists.

Have the data as an object. This way finding the value will be O(1). and will increase readability. Also have the array as a computed property.

```
export default {
  name: 'list',
  data: () => ({
    data: {
      'id1': {id: 'id1', state: 'pending'},
      'id2': {id: 'id2', state: 'allowed'},
      'id3': {id: 'id3', state: 'rejected'},
    },
  }),
  computed: {
    dataList() {
      return Object.values(this.data)
    },
    pendingData() {
        return this.dataList.filter(x => x.state === 'pending')
    },
    allowedData() {
        return this.dataList.filter(x => x.state === 'allowed')
    },
    rejectedData() {
        return this.dataList.filter(x => x.state === 'rejected')
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setState(id, state) {
    this.$axios.post(`/api/${id}`, {state})
      .then(res => {
          Object.assign(this.data[id], res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          this.$notify(err, 'danger')
      })
    }
  }
};
```

Then you just use in the template like so:

```html
<div v-for="item of pendingData" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
</div>

<div v-for="item of  allowedData" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
</div>

<div v-for="item of rejectedData" :key="item.id">
    <!-- data card body (including buttons) -->
</div>
```

NOTE: Code changed after author's comment to my response. so this way you avoid v-if because you are already iterating over different lists.

Comment: There's no such thing as filter. All three lists are rendered simultaneously. The only difference in the template is that `v-if` is added to `v-for`s, so computed properties and `findIndex` are omitted.