# v-if condition get error message in vue.js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5

working with Laravel + Vue Project. and I have following code segments in the mainapp.vue file

```
<div class="_1side_menu_list">
            <ul class="_1side_menu_list_ul">
              <li v-for="(menuItem, i) in permission" :key="i" v-if="permission.length && menuItem.read">
                <router-link :to="'/'+menuItem.name"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> {{menuItem.resourceName}}</router-link>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/logout"><Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

but in the following line `v-if="permission.length && menuItem.read"` highlighting in the id and display following error message `[vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for]`  | `The 'permission' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'.`

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to handle v-if with v-for in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518609/correct-way-to-handle-v-if-with-v-for-in-vue)

Answer (score 1):

`v-if` cant be use with `v-for`

see example i used template to avoid render extra element

1st use `v-for` and inside this loop use `v-if`

```js
<div class="_1side_menu_list">
  <ul class="_1side_menu_list_ul">
    <template v-for="(menuItem, i) in permission" :key="i">
      <li v-if="permission.length && menuItem.read">
        <router-link :to="'/'+menuItem.name">
          <Icon type="ios-speedometer" /> {{menuItem.resourceName}}
        </router-link>
       </li>
     </template>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: still get error with `:key="i` code segments